# Django invalidate previous unexpired reset password tokens

Tags: django

If a user send multiple password reset token, how can I invalidate previous unexpired tokens?

Answer (score 1):

The token is [based on the salted password](https://github.com/django/django/blob/c52ecbda615594750ae59b789313a29893950b3d/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py#L65), so as soon as the password is changed, any other reset tokens will be invalid.

Apart from that, it isn't possible to invalidate the tokens. You could change the [`PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#password-reset-timeout-days) setting (it defaults to 3) so that they expire sooner.

Comment: if i want to expiry my token in 3 hrs what i have do ?

Comment: @javedgouri There is [a ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28622) to allow values less than one day, but at the moment it is not possible.